# Visual Studio 2008 HTML formatting - does it ever work?

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, formatting

It's another Visual Studio 2008 HTML formatting question...I think I have either found a bug in the infamously bad VS HTML formatting, or I'm doing something wrong. Here's what I'm doing:

**I remove all client side tags via:**
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Format -> Tag Specific options

**I then add b and span tags:**

[alt text http://www.xtupload.com/new/thumb-3BB0_49B92330.jpg](http://www.xtupload.com/new/share-3BB0_49B92330.html)

I press CTRL+E,CTRL+D and I get these two differing results:

### 1

[alt text http://www.xtupload.com/new/image-CBF1_49B92330.jpg](http://www.xtupload.com/new/image-CBF1_49B92330.jpg)
The P before the span tag isn't formatted properly

### 2

[alt text http://www.xtupload.com/new/image-3AB6_49B92330.jpg](http://www.xtupload.com/new/image-3AB6_49B92330.jpg)
The P tag is formatted correctly.

*This for a .ASPX extension file.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like it is a bug, and isn't dependent on the tag being SPAN or B.

## The work around I found

Add an extra space before the closing P.

### How it fails

```
<p><b>My title</b></p>
```

Gets re-formatted as

```
<p>
  <b>My title</b></p>
```

### How to get it to work

```
<p><b>My title</b> </p>
```

*(NB the space after the B)* gets reformatted as:

```
<p>
  <b>My title</b>
</p>
```

And that extra space is removed by VS anyway. Hallelujah my HTML looks beautiful!

Answer (score 2):

I followed the same method as Chris. I decided to use a RegEx find and replace to do it for the whole document.  The regex finds any closing p or h* tags that aren't preceded by white space or the start of a line and inserts a newline before the closing tag.  Examine the regex to get a better understanding.  Here's what I used:

Find what:

```
{[^:b^]}{\</(p|(h:z))\>}:b*$
```

Replace with:

```
\1\n\2
```

It only finds p and h* because those were the only two I found had this problem. Other tags can be added.

Comment: Had the same issue in VS2010, albeit with different tags.  Regex was most helpful to plough through it.  Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

You can customize the layout per tag, if it bothers you that much. Go to the options dialog and select the formatting option under Text Editor -> HTML

Having said that, I don't like some of the inconsistencies I couldn't fix, so I stopped using it except to reformat code from someone else before I started working on it. Once the initial reformat is done, I maintain the formatting manually.

Comment: That's what I'm doing already (first image). I'm trying to figure out if it will behave how I want it to, or if I should just give up and find another tool to auto-format with, and then copy it back in. Doing that seems to defeat the point of the IDE though